# Where to ask questions about computer vision?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where to ask questions about computer vision? I see there are tags for CV on both [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision) and [Robotics SE](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision). Both sites have equally about 100 question tagged with CV.

I would like to ask about monocular visual odometry - is that a better fit for Robotics?

Comment: some helpful suggestions at [Stack Exchange site to ask questions about computer vision?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2794/163067)

Comment: stack overflow, because often that stuff _is_ about programming... and even when you're just asking about approaches, ehhhhh, you tend to get a bunch of suggestions in the comments at least